# Mongodb + Stacked Highcharts

Tags: mongodb, highcharts, mean-stack, stacked

I am learning Mongodb and am trying to implement stacked highcharts from Mongodb. I am struggling to display the data to match the highcharts document. This what I have done so far:

**Mongodb document:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a.....b"),
    "to: "Jane",
    "mode" : "Open"
}
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("576a.....c"),
     "to: "Jane",
    "mode" : "Closed"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a.....d"),
    "to: "Smith",
    "mode" : "Open"
}
```

**Mongodb aggregate:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$group : {
    _id : {"to" : "$to", "mode": "$mode"},
    y : {$sum : 1}
}
}, {
$project : {
    "to" : "$_id.to",
    "mode" : "$_id.mode",
    "_id" : 0,
    "y" : "$y"
}
}, {
$group : {
    _id : {"to" : "$to" },
    items : {$push : {item : "$mode", qty: "$y"}}
}
}
])
```

**The output I got:**

```
[{
    "_id" : {
    "to" : "Jane"
},
"items" : [{
    "item" : "Open",
    "qty" : 1
}, {
    "item" : "Closed",
    "qty" : 1

}]
}, {
    "_id" : {
    "to" : "Smith"
},
"items" : [{
    "item" : "Open",
    "qty" : 1
}]

}

}]
```

Instead, I want the following output to display the highcharts:

```
categories = ["Jane","Smith"]
series = [{
    name : 'Open',
    data: [1,1]  //1 -open jane, 1- open smith
}, {
    name : 'Closed',
    data : [1,0]  //1 - closed jane, 0- closed smith

}]
```

Any idea how to get this output? Thanks!

Comment: Anybody who can help me with the mongodb aggregation to get the expected result?

Comment: It is not possible to get result with `categories =` and `series =` But you can create the described structure using `map` or `forEach` methods. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the parser, which converts your JSON from mongoDB to right format.

```
var data = [{
    "_id": {
      "to": "Jane"
    },
    "items": [{
      "item": "Open",
      "qty": 1
    }, {
      "item": "Closed",
      "qty": 1

    }]
  }, {
    "_id": {
      "to": "Smith"
    },
    "items": [{
      "item": "Open",
      "qty": 1
    }]
  }];

  var outputSeries = [{
      name: 'Open',
      data: []
    }, {
      name: 'Closed',
      data: []
    }],
    each = Highcharts.each;

  each(data, function(serie, i) {
    each(serie.items, function(point, j) {
      if (point.item === 'Open') {
        outputSeries[0].data.push(point.qty);
      } else if (point.item === 'Closed') {
        outputSeries[1].data.push(point.qty);
      }
    });
  });
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/hbqfn0yr/